# Going out of memory

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf-data-services

I am using WCF data service to get data from server within my winforms application.
I am trying to show bulky report having millions of records.
Although i am fetching data page wise and storing into a collection but going out of memory.

Here is the code used to find total records and allocate memory for List.

```
int totalRecords = ReportingService.Instance.CountRecords_ReportItemWiseSell(d1, d2);
List<Report_ItemWiseSellEntity> reportItems = new List<Report_ItemWiseSellEntity>(totalRecords);
```

Here is the code to collect all paged data

```
int totalPageCount = (totalRecords / pageSize) + 1;
lvReport.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 1; i <= totalPageCount; i++){
   var tmpItems = new List<Report_ItemWiseSellEntity>();
   tmpItems = ReportingService.Instance.GetItemWiseSellReport(d1, d2, i, pageSize);
   reportItems.AddRange(tmpItems);

   ... //other stuff
   tmpItems = null;
   Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Can anybody suggest how to overcome this memory issue. Is there any other alternative?
Thanks for sharing your wisdom and time.

Comment: Which one is out of memory, the WinForms app or WCF?

Comment: Also, what sort of data structures are contains in `Report_ItemWiseSellEntity`?

Comment: On which line do you get the OutOfMemoryException?
It seems that your for loop loops through every page and load items. If that is the case, why does it? The idea with paging should be to load just the page that is currently displayed into memory.

Comment: What has your user done to deserve the punishment of having to read through millions of rows? Isn't he/she looking for something in particular and doesn't it make more sense to let him/her enter these filter criteria before stuffing millions of rows in a list?

Comment: This is a code for showing report to user. The report is fetched for given date range. There is about 90000 records for a period of 3 months, which increases or decreases based on date range. I am just fetching those calculated rows dividing into pages. Which is then shown in the GridView and also exported to Excel or other formats.

Comment: For the purpose of exporting i need to store them into a List.

Comment: Why don't you answer some of the questions in these comments if you want someone to help... particularly @mortb's re where the exception occurs.

Comment: No i am not getting OutOfMemoryException, instead i am getting null in tmpItems during fetching certain data pages.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. What made you say it was "a memory issue"? What led you to put "out of memory" in the title?

Comment: @IrfanRaza As in ReportingService.Instance.GetItemWiseSellReport() returns null ? If so you will have to supply the code for that function. And you are aware that unless you are the only user on that database or completly lock it down that the asynch count and fetch calls are not guaranteed complete/correct if there are changes made to the database in between the calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless  `... // other stuff` contains something crucial to the issue, your fetching of data page-wise isn't helping with memory consumption on the WinForms side, since you are cumulatively adding all the instances of `Report_ItemWiseSellEntity` retrieved from the service into the `reportItems` list.

Since your UI is never going to be able to display "millions of records" at the same time, your strategy should be to hold in memory in the WinForms application only those records which are currently being displayed/processed at any time. You will need to rethink your design for binding data to the UI and coordinate retrieving of "pages" of data with the user's navigation of the report through the UI.

Comment: The other stuff is confirmly not blocking anything. When i execute the report there are about 8 pages fetched and loaded out of 13 for a period of three months. For lower date ranges like 15 days the report is properly loaded.